# как фильтровать сообщения с символом "+" telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть код который проверяет qiwi токен и вносить его в базу, но он работает только если номер введен без знака +. Как можно установить фильтор, чтоб если сообщение с номером содержит + бот писал, что нужно без плюса.
Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.chat.id == settings.admin or message.chat.id == settings.admin2:
       if message.text == "qiwi":
         try:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Введите логин(номер без '+') QIWI кошелька")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_qiwi_number)
         except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Введите логин(номер без '+') QIWI кошелька")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_qiwi_number)


def change_qiwi_number(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Введите токен QIWI API")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Введите токен QIWI API")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_qiwi_token)
    global qiwi_login
    qiwi_login = message.text

def change_qiwi_token(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Проверка введённых QIWI данных...")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Проверка введённых QIWI данных...")
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        request = requests.Session()
        request.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + message.text  
        parameters = {"rows": 5, "operation" : "IN"}
        selectQiwi = request.get("https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v2/persons/" + qiwi_login + "/payments", params = parameters)
        if selectQiwi.status_code == 200:   
            with sqlite3.connect("base_ts.sqlite", detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES) as con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM qiwi")
                while True:
                    row = cur.fetchone()
                    if row == None:
                        break
                    cur.execute("UPDATE qiwi SET login = ?, token = ? WHERE login = ?", (qiwi_login, message.text, row[0]))
            if con:
                con.close()
            try:
                bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "✅ QIWI токен был успешно изменён")
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "✅ QIWI токен был успешно изменён")
        else:
            try:
                bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "❌ QIWI токен не прошёл проверку. Код ошибки: " + str(selectQiwi.status_code))
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "❌ QIWI токен не прошёл проверку. Код ошибки: " + str(selectQiwi.status_code))
    except:
        try:
            bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "❌ QIWI токен не прошёл проверку.\nВведённые вами данные не верны")
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:     
            bot.delete_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id + 1)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "❌ QIWI токен не прошёл проверку.\nВведённые вами данные не верны")
```

Comment: Неужели, человек написавший этот код, не может проверить наличие + в строке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать так, чтобы было не важно как пользователь введет номер телефона, с плюсом или без

```
qiwi_login = message.text
if '+' in qiwi_login:
    qiwi_login = message.text.lstrip("+")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, qiwi_login)
else:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, qiwi_login)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно удалять в введённом номере *"+"* с помощью строкового метода **lstrip()**. По умолчанию без аргументов он возвращает копию строки без пробелов слева, а если в неё передать аргумент в виде символа, то удалит в строке слева указанный в аргументе символ.

```
qiwi_login = message.text.lstrip("+")
```

А если всё же с помощью проверки хочешь сделать, то нужно использовать метод **startswith**, он вернёт True если строка начинается с заданного символа.

```
qiwi_login = message.text
if qiwi_login.startswith("+"):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите номер без +")
else:
    ...
```